# VB grab text from selected form

Tags: vb.net, textbox, mdi

I was wondering how you would grab some text from a textbox in a selected form. I have a MDI form which contains X number of child forms. Each child form has a textbox in it with some text. When I hit the save button how do I know which form is selected and how do I grab the text from that textbox.

```
Private Sub Forms_Clicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Forms.clicked
    globalVar = sender
End Sub
```

I was thinking to make an event that just detects when ever a form is clicked and save it's form/form ID in a global variable. Any thoughts?

Comment: where does the save button reside? is there one on each form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like bodjo said, you have the [YourMDIForm].ActiveMDIChild property.

What is unclear, like Plutonix said is where is your Save "Button". Did you meant :

- a Save MenuItem from a MenuStrip on your MDI Parent Form ?
- or a Save Button inside an MDI Child Form (or either another Form that is not part of the MDI Parent/Child system)

The first case is pretty straightforward : Use the `.ActiveMDIChild` of your MDIParent Form.
The secund may need some valid way to point to an actual active child form (similar to the one you tried with your `globalVar`... there are better ways to do it.

By the way, when you get your targeted MDIChild through .ActiveMDIChild, you must access the textbox with a Public, Friend or Protected variable. Usually, controls in forms are private. So you may have to :

```
Public Class [YourMDIChildClassName]
    ' ...

    ' create a Public Property
    Public ReadOnly Property ContentToSave() As String
        Get
            Return [YourTextBox].Text
        End Get
    End Property

    ' or make your textbox public in the Form design
    Public [YourTextBox] As TextBox

    ' ... the one or the other, not both.
    ' ...
End Class
```

Another way to access the "active" MDIChild, **assuming all of your MDIChild are instances of the same class** is to create a static (shared) property in your Child class :

```
Public Class [YourMDIChildClassName]
    ' ...

    Private Shared _CurrentMDIChild As [YourMDIChildClassName] = Nothing

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property CurrentMDIChild() As [YourMDIChildClassName]
        Get
            Return _CurrentMDIChild
        End Get
    End Property

    ' ...
End Class
```

And using the same thing you tried, but using .Activated instead of .Clicked

```
Public Class [YourMDIChildClassName]
    ' ...

    Private Sub MyChildForm_Activated() Handles Me.Activated
        _CurrenMDIChild = Me
    End Sub
    ' And that's ALL this method SHOULD contain.
    ' If you try to add other activation tricks, like activating another Form, 
    ' or firing up a DialogBox (worst case), 
    ' everything will go WRONG and your application will hang in an endless loop !!!
    ' Be carefull when using .Activated.

    ' ...
End Class
```

Then you could access the currently active MDIChild using the static Property :

```
[YourMDIChildClassName].CurrentMDIChild
' => Gives you directly a VALID instance of your MDI Child (or Nothing !)
' Then you can use in your MDI Parent :
If [YourMDIChildClassName].CurrentMDIChild IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim TextToSave As String = [YourMDIChildClassName].CurrentMDIChild.ContentToSave
    ' ... save your text...
End If
```

**HOWEVER**, because you've created a static (shared) pointer to the last active MDIChild *(sort of, I know it's not a pointer like in C)* **you must update this pointer whenever you close an MDIChild Form !**

```
Public Class [YourMDIChildClassName]
    ' ...

    Private Sub [YourMDIChildClassName]_FormClosing( _
        sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        If _CurrentMDIChild Is Me Then ' And "Me" is closing right now...
            _CurrentMDIChild = Nothing
            ' We don't want memory leak or pointer to a Form that has been closed !
        End If
    End Sub

    ' ...
End Class
```

We are not supposed to create custom way of handling Child Form activation. `MDIParent.ActiveMDIChild` is there for that. However, once we want to access **extended/custom/specific** Properties of the Child Form that doesn't initially exists in `System.Windows.Forms.Form`, we need to cast the `MDIParent.ActiveMDIChild` to the real Form derived Type of our MDIChild. That's one other way to do it, but it's just me : I don't like castings much. Always set IDE to :

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off
```

---

`Forms.Clicked` ... does this event (Clicked) really exist ? I'm aware of `.Click` but not "Clicked". Anyway :

```
Public Class [YourMDIChildClassName]
    ' ...

    Private Sub MyChildForm_Clicked() Handles Me.Click
        ' This part is executed when you click INSIDE the Form,
        ' at a location where there is NO Control.
        ' If you click on a control, like a Textbox, a Picturebox, a Panel, etc
        ' this block IS NOT EXECUTED as you've clicked on a control, 
        ' not on the Form !
    End Sub

    ' ...
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you . Yes save is in my parent MDI menu strip Your answer should work. I'll try it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to [determine the active child from](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984347(v=vs.71).aspx) first and from there, you can check which text box you want to read its content.